# $A,B$ are bounded linear operators, $AB\geq 0$ implies ($A\geq 0$ and $B\geq 0$) or ($-A\geq 0$ and $-B\geq 0$)?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $F$ be a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

> Assume that
>
> Let $A,B\in\mathcal{B}(F)$ be such that
>
> - $AB\geq 0$ (i.e. $\langle ABx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$).
> - $\|AB\|=\|BA\|$.
>
> I claim that ($A\geq 0$ and $B\geq 0$) or ($-A\geq 0$ and $-B\geq 0$). Is it possible to prove the claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't assume anything else about the operators then I think it is false. Define $A(x)=ix$ and $B(x)=-ix$. Obviously none of them is positive and none of them is negative. But $\langle AB(x),x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$. And we also have $||AB||=||BA||$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What should I assume about $A$ and $B$ in order to get the result?

Comment: Not sure. I know that if $A,B$ are self adjoint and positive, and also $AB=BA$ then $AB\geq 0$. But I'm not sure the converse is true.

Comment: Juste I have a remark positive operator on complex Hilbert space is self-adjoint.

Comment: Yes, if $\langle Ax,x\rangle\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in F$ (when $F$ is a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$) then it implies the operator is self adjoint. Obviously this shows a positive operator must be self adjoint. In the example I gave you in my answer $A$ and $B$ were not self adjoint, hence not positive. But $AB$ was positive.

Comment: Yes Thank you. I think also that if $A^2$ is positive, this not implie that $A$ is positive or $-A$ is positive.

Comment: I also think it doesn't. Though there is a theorem that if $B\geq 0$ then there is a unique positive operator $X$ such that $X^2=B$. So if $A^2$ is positive then it has a positive "square root". But $A$ and $-A$ are not the only square roots of $A^2$.

Answer (score 2):

If the dimension is at least two, the answer is "no", even in the case of real spaces. Take
$$
A=B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $AB=A^2=BA=I\geq0$, but neither $A\geq0$ nor $-A\geq0$.

Comment: To simplify: if $A^2$ is positive, when $A$ is also positive? Thank you.

Comment: There is no obvious answer to that, it depends on what you know about  $A $. Squaring kills lots of things. Any matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ (1-a^2)/b& -a\end{bmatrix} $ satisfies $A^2=I $; so $A $ doesn't even have to be selfadjoint, let alone positive.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrices.